Why is $\chi_{\mathbb C[G]}(a, b) = |\{x\in G\mid axb^{-1} = x\}|$?
Let $G$ be a finite group and let $G\times G$ act linearly on $\mathbb C[G]$ by setting
$$(a, b)\cdot g = agb^{-1}$$
and extending linearly. Then my professor said
$$\chi_{\mathbb C[G]}(a, b) = |\{x\in G\mid axb^{-1} = x\}|$$
Why is this true?

This is just a computation. The elements of $G$ form a standard basis of $\mathbb{C}[G]$, and the element $(a,b)$ defines a linear transformation on $\mathbb{C}[G]$. How does the matrix of this transformation with respect to the standard basis look like?

It's a permutation matrix which has a 1 in the entry on the main diagonal corresponding to each group element $x$ such that $axb^{-1} = 1$. And it has a $0$ in the other entries of the main diagonal. Thanks!
